# I am downloading a file as zip but when download extension not coming

Tags: c#

I am downloading file as zip extension but when it download no extension is coming.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="ABC.zip");
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET app?

Comment: Are you sure that code is executed? Because that code does not compile. Should be something similar to `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"ABC.zip\"");`

Comment: Are you sure that the extension isn't sent? Or is it Windows that is hiding it from you? (remember, we cannot see what is happening at your side)

Answer (score 0):

Have you sent the right content type?

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

Also noticed you may have an error, it should be the following...

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ABC.zip");
```

Comment: The overload is fine, it is [HttpResponse.AddHeader(string name, string value)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.addheader?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpResponse_AddHeader_System_String_System_String_) but the question code is wrong, does not compile

Comment: Since the code in the question won't compile because of the extra quote character, I'm assuming that is not a real problem but more a symptom of rewriting the code instead of copy/paste.